# Річка і місто Ірпінь - чоловічий чи жіночий рід?

Tags: власні-назви

Йдеться про річку і однойменне місто в Київський області. На письмі і в усному мовленні зустрічаю обидва варіанти, хтось каже *під Ірпінню*, *за Ірпінню*, а хтось *під Ірпенем*, *за Ірпенем*. В словниках інформації не знайшов.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ [кажуть](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D1%96%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%8C):

> Ірпі́нь — іменник чоловічого роду:
>
> називний — Ірпі́нь
>   родовий — Ірпеня́
>   давальний — Ірпеню́, Ірпене́ві
>   знахідний — Ірпі́нь
>   орудний — Ірпене́м
>   місцевий — Ірпені́, Ірпеню́
>   кличний — Ірпеню́

Якщо зайти через [офіційний інтерфейс](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), то там ще написано:

> (річка; місто в Україні)